# How to get coordinate from spline interpolation

Tags: interpolation, splines

[image]

Hi, I would like to find 10 coordinates between each points of this spline interpolation. I have done some research, but cannot find an appropriate answer. Any help will be appreciated.

```
pts = {{2.8, 1.5}, {5.2, 2.8}, {4.1, 4.4}, {1.6, 1.6}, {3.1, 0.5}, {6.8, 2}, {7.5, 4.5}, 
 {8, 8.8}, {9, 11}, {11.5, 12}, {13.2, 10.8}, {11, 8}, {9.8, 9.2}, {12, 11}};
{xs, ys} = Transpose[pts];
xinterp = Interpolation[xs, Method -> "Spline"];
yinterp = Interpolation[ys, Method -> "Spline"];
ParametricPlot[{xinterp[t], yinterp[t]}, {t, 1, Length@pts}, 
Epilog -> Point /@ pts]
```

Comment: `Table[{xinterp[t], yinterp[t]}, {t, 1, Length@pts, 1/11}]`

Answer (score 5):

As Karsten mentions in a comment to your question,

```
morePts = Table[{xinterp[t], yinterp[t]}, {t, 1, Length@pts, 1/11}];
```

will give you original points along with the addition points you asked for. The plot of the curve with the additional points is given by

```
ParametricPlot[{xinterp[t], yinterp[t]}, {t, 1, Length @ pts}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[morePts], 
  Blue, AbsolutePointSize[3], Point[pts]}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks! This is what I have been looking for. I really appreciate it =)